# Split the expression String as ArrayList

Tags: java, string, split

I  have a expression string as

```
"((firstname = john AND Lastname = Eleven) OR (salary = 15000 AND location = Mexico OR (firstname = mathew AND lastname = Thirteen)))";
```

Is there any builtin function i can split them as `List<String>` having in below format :

```
list[0] = "(";
list[1] = "(";
list[2] = "firstname";
list[3] = "=";
list[4] = "john"
list[5] = "AND";
list[6] = "Lastname"
list[7] = "=";
list[8] = "Eleven";
list[9] = ")"
list[10] = "OR"
list[11] = "(";
list[12] = "salary";
list[13] = "15000"
list[14] = "AND"
etc...
```

Comment: Have you tried using a regex?

Comment: try `string.split`

Comment: I suggest you to read this turorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: problem with split(regex), i cannot get the operator i am using for split. For example if I use ( or ) to split i cannot get ( in the result list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace all `(` or `)` woth `space $1 space` then split with space :

```
String spl[] = 
       str.replaceAll("([\\(\\)=])", " $1 ").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim().split("\\s");
```

**Outputs**

```
(, (, firstname, =, john, AND, Lastname, =, Eleven, ), OR, (, salary, =, 15000, AND, 
location, =, Mexico, OR, (, firstname, =, mathew, AND, lastname, =, Thirteen, ), ), )
```

Comment: This looks promising just  edited as split("\\s+"). so second replaceAll is not required

Comment: i already edit my answer @CrazyProgrammer i was making a mistake now, it work fine

Comment: @CrazyProgrammer you have to not use `\\s+` if you check you can get `=, Eleven),` and this is not correct instead use my solution like it is, it work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `split` with multiple delimeters

```
String[] tokens = exp.split("\\(|\\)| |=");
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally this process is called [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis):

> In computer science, **lexical analysis** is the process of **converting a sequence of characters** (such as in a computer program or web page) **into a sequence of tokens** (strings with an assigned and thus identified meaning)

This can be done defining a [lexical grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_grammar):

> a **lexical grammar** is a formal grammar **defining the syntax of tokens**

Once defined the lexical grammar is possible to use tools like JavaCC or JFlex that convert that grammar in a lexer, that is basically a software that take as input a sequence of characters and generate as output a list of tokens.

Note that a lexical analyzer not only splits the original sequence of chars in a sequence of strings, but in a more specific sequence of tokens, something like:

```
OPEN_PARANTHESIS
OPEN_PARANTHESIS
NAME with value firstname
OPERATOR with value =
NAME with value john
OPERATOR with value AND
NAME with value Lastname
OPERATOR with value =
...
```

So it does something more than what you asked, but your question seems very related to it.

Comment: This looks very interesting and the best way of implementation. If you can help me with some example, i will try using them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lookahead` and `lookbehind` with `regex` to get the tokens and iterate over it, e.g.:

```
String s = "((firstname = john AND Lastname = Eleven) OR (salary = 15000 AND location = Mexico OR (firstname = mathew AND lastname = Thirteen))";
for(String token : s.split("((?=(\\(|\\)|\\=|\\sAND\\s|\\sOR\\s))|(?<=(\\(|\\)|\\=|\\sAND\\s|\\sOR\\s)))")){
    System.out.println(token.trim());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"((firstname = john AND Lastname = Eleven) OR (salary = 15000 AND location = Mexico OR (firstname = mathew AND lastname = Thirteen)))";
```

Give the whitespace between " `((`" like this:

```
String exp = "( ( firstname = john AND Lastname = Eleven ) OR ( salary = 15000 AND location = Mexico OR ( firstname = mathew AND lastname = Thirteen ) ) )";
```

Now you can  split by using `exp.split( " ");`

Comment: You should not be changing the expression itself just to use `split` function

Comment: As per coding standards any expression should have spaces b/w curlie braces

Comment: Can you show working code that puts whitespace in the right places?  That's close to being an equivalent problem, so you're not providing much of an answer here.